# How to get output from system('cat') to show on apache web page?

Tags: c, apache

I've been tasked with upgrading some old servers (ubuntu 9 -> ubuntu 14). On our old server, we have some C scripts which use this format to output file content:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <strings.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

main(argc, argv)
    int argc;
    int argv;
{
    printf("content-type: text/plain\n\n");
    printf("Normal Output...\n");
    system("cat /path/to/file");
    printf("Done...\n");
}
```

Now, if I compile this into a cgi script and run it from the web on our old server, I see the content of /path/to/file. However on any newer apache server, it doesn't show me the cat output. I know it shows when it runs on the command line and I know the command actually runs from the web because I can use "> log" to redirect the cat output. Does anybody know what I can do to make these system cat outputs work with apache?

EDIT:
It seems I can do that with perl in a very similar fashion and get what I am looking for, so I would imagine it's a C-specific problem and not apache. Here's a perl script which does do what I expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "Normal Output...\n";
system("cat /path/to/file");
print "Done...\n";
```

EDIT 2:

I figured out a way to get the original code to work as expected without utilizing an alternate method of reading file. I wasn't looking for how to read the content of the text files, but rather what I would have to do to make this script, and others like it, work. I figured out that adding fflush makes the above code work as expected. I'm sorry if my question was vague, I was just trying find a quick solution for a problem that will be dealt with by other people at another time.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <strings.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

main(argc, argv)
    int argc;
    int argv;
{
    printf("content-type: text/plain\n\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Normal Output...\n");
    system("cat /path/to/file");
    printf("Done...\n");
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `fopen` etc instead of `system`?

Comment: @EdHeal, I'm not the one writing these scripts or meaning to find a better way. I'm saying that I have quite a number of scripts laying around which already use this syntax on the other server, and we don't want to go through and find/rewrite many dozens of scripts.

Comment: Apache configuration file will have list of filetypes which are executable: .php .cgi and so on.  Either edit your config file, or alter the file extension on your cgi scripts.

Comment: @ArifBurhan The C program is compiled and named as a cgi, as is my perl example above. They both run, but C doesn't show the the content of the cat while the perl script does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store the Output of System function to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998228/how-can-i-store-the-output-of-system-function-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

From the [system() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system): "system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns after the command has been completed."

And that's about all it does. You want something like `popen`, which can start another process and will return an IO stream so you can read from / write to the process.

BUT! if all you want is a C program that displays the contents of a text file, then using `system()` to run `cat` is a bit excessive. Just use C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;

    /* Open the file */
    if ((fp = fopen("/path/to/file", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("failed to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("content-type: text/plain\n\n");
    printf("Normal Output...\n");

    /* Print each character in the file */
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");

    fclose(fp); /* close the file */
    printf("Done...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use `fgets()` ([man page here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)) instead of `fgetc`, if you know your file will contain newline-seperated text and you want to read whole lines at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that this is the proper way to get the content and print it, and whomever wrote my example script in the past did it quite an odd way. I'm not a C programmer, per se, just an admin trying to work it out without having to rewrite a ridiculous amount of scripts. I actually did figure out how to get my program to do what you want with minimal work: I just had to add "fflush(stdout)" before the strcopy and it works like magic.

Comment: strcpy? there's no strcpy in the code you posted above

Answer (score 0):

You can use popen instead of system.

Here is the popen code,

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <strings.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
        printf("content-type: text/plain\n\n");
        printf("Normal Output...\n");
        FILE *fp;
        char buffer[1024];
        if((fp = popen("cat /path/to/file", "r")) != NULL)
        {
                while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)
                {
                        printf("%s", buffer);
                }
                printf("\n");
                printf("Done...\n");
        }
}
```

The popen function executes that command and store the output to the Temporary file. And it returns the file pointer to that temporary file.

**UPDATE:-**

There is a second method is also there to do this.
That is,

Store the system output to a file, and read that file.

Here is the code for second method.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <strings.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
        printf("content-type: text/plain\n\n");
        printf("Normal Output...\n");
        FILE *fp;
        char buffer[1024];
        system("cat file.txt > output.txt");
        if((fp = fopen("output.txt", "r")) != NULL)
        {
                while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)
                {
                        printf("%s", buffer);
                }
                printf("\n");
                printf("Done...\n");
        }
}
```